# Aggregating BIT values into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL tableA have 4 rows of Data, with 3 columns.

[image]

Expected Result is :

[image]

Expected Logic is : In SectorTestRequiured is having two TRUE value column data so expected is TRUE. ( if alteat one column value is true , expected o/p should be true)

From given example :

SectorDetailsRequired column has all Zero values rows hence expected o/p is FALSE.

SectorTestRequired have one or more True value column data so o/p is TRUE.

OtherInfoRequired have all the column data as True so o/p is TRUE.

NOTE: I am using BIT Values , so `MAX`, `SUM` won't work as provided in answers given below.

Comment: select max(c1), max(c2), max(c3) from table

Comment: so does the column require at least 2 TRUE values in order to display TRUE in the aggregated results? You state:: *In SectorTestRequiured is having two TRUE value column*

Comment: atleast one True value column is enough. & it's an bit value field. So Max , SUM will be applied ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've understood your question to require a column has 2 TRUE values in order to output a TRUE value in the aggregated results, so I `COUNT` the `TRUE` values and used `CASE WHEN` to output `1` or `0` depending on the count being `>=2`:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
    (
      SectorDetailsRequired BIT ,
      SectorTestRequired BIT ,
      OtherInfoRequired BIT
    )

INSERT  INTO #tmp
        ( SectorDetailsRequired, SectorTestRequired, OtherInfoRequired )
VALUES  ( 0, 1, 1 ),
        ( 0, 1, 1 ),
        ( 0, 0, 1 ),
        ( 0, 0, 1 )

SELECT  CASE WHEN COUNT(NULLIF(SectorDetailsRequired, 0)) >= 2 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END SectorDetailsRequired ,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(NULLIF(SectorTestRequired, 0)) >= 2 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END SectorTestRequired ,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(NULLIF(OtherInfoRequired, 0)) >= 2 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END OtherInfoRequired
FROM    #tmp

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

**Outputs:**

```
SectorDetailsRequired   SectorTestRequired  OtherInfoRequired
0                       1                   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum the columns and apply logic based on what you need the sum to be. I'm not sure I interpreted your requirements correctly, but this should give you a clue what to do:

```
SELECT
   CASE SUM(CAST(SectorDetailsRequired AS int)) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS SectorDetailsRequired,
   CASE SUM(CAST(SectorTestRequired AS int)) WHEN >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SectorTestRequired,
   CASE SUM(CAST(OtherInfoRequested AS int)) WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS END OtherInfoRequested
FROM <your table>
```

Comment: `SUM` won't work without conversion/casting if the underlying data type is BIT (TRUE/FALSE)

Comment: Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator. Because of BIT operator.

Comment: @Tanner you are right, thanks. Answer has been edited.

Comment: @Vinod it was a casting issue I fixed by Tanner's suggestion